# Full page responsive background of nested divs

Tags: css, html

I made a BG made of CSS clipping in several divs (nested in `.background`) how do I configure the whole thing to be responsive? When I set width or height to 100% the background does not render at all.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0px;
}

.bg0 {
  position: relative;
  width: 1366px;
  height: 675px;
  background-color: #3B3B3B;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.bg1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333333;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 80% 0, 35% 50%, 0 12%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 80% 0, 35% 50%, 0 12%);
}

.bg2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #2D2D2D;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 12%, 0 86%, 35% 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 12%, 0 86%, 35% 50%);
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="background">
    <div class="bg0"></div>
    <div class="bg1"></div>
    <div class="bg2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Content!!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First....Why are you using fixed width to the `bg0` class and also you are giving width to `bg0` class grater than its parent element `#wrapper`...

I don think it's required...Just set the `width` and `height` of `.background` class

***Stack Snippet***

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0px;
}

.bg0 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #3B3B3B;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.bg1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333333;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 80% 0, 35% 50%, 0 12%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 80% 0, 35% 50%, 0 12%);
}

.bg2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #2D2D2D;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 12%, 0 86%, 35% 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 12%, 0 86%, 35% 50%);
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="background">
    <div class="bg0"></div>
    <div class="bg1"></div>
    <div class="bg2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Content!!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```